# Set a server context path for tomcat when launching in a docker container

Tags: docker, tomcat8, catalina

I am running tomcat in a docker container like this

```
FROM myregistry/cfw-deploy-base

COPY ./my.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/

ENV JAVA_OPTS=""

CMD ["/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

However, the context path is set based on the war file name (`my` in this case)
I want to set the context path from an environment variable configured inside the container.
Can I set it when using `catalina.sh`?

Comment: You want to know how to use env variable inside Dockerfile?

Comment: See https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/master/9.0/jre8-alpine/Dockerfile for reference

Comment: @Marged Which part in the file is relevant to context path?

Comment: @Maroun No, I want to konw how can I set context path in tomcat 8 using an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be copy your *.war file to webapps folder with desired name. It can be easily done, by modifying line:

```
COPY ./my.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/
```

to

```
COPY ./my.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/myContext.war
```

This change would make your app available under `<server>:<port>/myContext` path. If you wish to have context path specified under environment variable, you can modify your script to:

```
ENV MY_CONTEXT=contextName
COPY ./my.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/${MY_CONTEXT}.war
```

Setting up application context explicitly with Tomcat means can be done with these steps:

1. Go to your application META-INF folder (in your case: /opt/tomcat/webapps/my/META-INF)
2. Create XML file: `context.xml` and paste this content:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/myContext"/>
> ```

3. Restart Tomcat

With some effort you should be able to automate these steps in your Dockerfile.

Comment: I'm trying the `context.xml` approach (using tomcat:9-jre8-alpine) but TomCat is still setting the context path based on the .war file name. Any ideas as to why?